# Avoiding segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, scanf, strcmp

I'm trying to port a software to Linux. It works greatly on Windows.
On Linux it gives me a segmentation fault on strcmp:

```
int main(void) {
    ...
    char* comando;
    char istruzione[100];
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", istruzione);
    comando = strtok(istruzione, " ");
    if (strcmp(comando, "fput") == 0)
    ...
}
```

The issue goes away using the array notation, but I need to use the * notation because I need to use strtok, which returns a * char.

Comment: What's `istruzione`?

Comment: Is istruzione already allocated? It needs to be for scanf()

Comment: I forgot to copy that portion of code. It's a simple array of char.

Comment: Are you also using comando after you use strcmp in your code ?

Comment: I found the solution. I didn't include the string.h header. So the question is: are there 2 implementation of strcmp, one in stdlib and one in string.h? And why the exact code works great with the string.h header on Windows?

Answer (score 3):

strtok can return NULL, which means you need to check for that before using it in strcmp.

Comment: Doing a simple check didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Doing a simple check would prevent you from using a NULL pointer in strcmp, and causing a segfault.  What did your check show?

Comment: The issue stays, because strtok is not returning NULL in this case.

Comment: If the code is raising a segmentation fault on strcmp even when you have tested explicitly that it is not null, it is very likely that strcmp is attempting to access memory beyond the 100 characters you have allocated for istruzione. That would happen if the program reads a line that is more than 100 characters long. Using `fgets` rather than `scanf` as I suggested would protect against that failure.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule in C, always check your return values, and always check that a pointer returned by a function is not NULL before attempting to do anything with it.

There's no telling what might have produced this segmentation fault without knowing the input to your program, but I would recommend very strongly that you avoid ever using `scanf`, which can produce segmentation faults or much worse. Here you could safely do this instead:

```
if (fgets(istruzione, 100, stdin) != NULL) {
    comando = strtok(istruzione, " \n");
    if (comando != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(comando, "fput") == 0) {
            ....
```

The `scanf` call you are using reads one line of text without copying the newline character. `fgets` reads the newline character, but you can tell `strtok` to just treat it as another delimiter in order to ignore it.

Comment: @OP - please check if this answer is what you need. I suggest you change all of your `scanf()` calls for `fgets()` aswell.

Comment: Already tried with fgets with no success. The only solution but not acceptable I found is to use an array instead of a pointer.

Comment: I think if you need more help with this, you will need to provide a complete (small) program and the input that causes it to segfault. fgets should guard against bad input, so I don't see any way that this code would generate a fault.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, `istruzione` is a simple char buffer, I put together the following test. One thing I observed with what you had, was that if you just hit ENTER as the input for the `scanf`, doing the `strcmp` would cause a segmentation fault. This was because `strtok` returns NULL since there's nothing to tokenize.

You may need to test if `strtok` is returning a NULL pointer before using `comando`. You can see how I did this in the following test code.

## scanf.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char istruzione[256];

int main(void) {
    char* comando;
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", istruzione);

    comando = strtok(istruzione, " ");

    /* test for NULL here */
    if (NULL != comando)
    {
        if (strcmp(comando, "fput") == 0)
            printf("%s\n", comando);
    }

    return 0;
}
```